# Userdefaults no longer removed when app is deleted

Tags: swiftui

I'm working on an app - storing 'didrunbefore' in UserDefaults to manage first-time-run. Its worked perfectly in testing up until recently. Seems that when I delete the app from a testing device (iPhoneX), the UserDefaults keys for the app are no longer deleted - whereas previously they were. I've checked my code to make sure I'm not setting them again accidentally before I run the check - literally can't explain it. This is on iOS 13 & 14. I've been using the beta of Xcode for development, but same issue happens in official Xcode release. Anyone else seeing this - is it the new norm?

UPDATED WITH CODE:

Here is where I check:

```
init() {
    if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "didLaunchBefore") {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "didLaunchBefore")
        currentPage = "xxx"
    } else  {
        currentPage = "yyy"
    }
```

Previously, I could delete the app from my device, reinstall via Xcode and UserDefaults would be blank and fresh. Now when I check that particular journey, UserDefaults are already populated with "didLaunchBefore = 1".

Comment: I am unable to replicate this issue. If you can update your question to include a [Minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that would be great.

Comment: Sorry, my first question here :)

Comment: Sorry @Andrew -  my first post here :) 

Here is where I check:

init() {
        if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "didLaunchBefore") {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "didLaunchBefore")
            currentPage = "xxx"
        } else  {
            currentPage = "yyy"
        }

Previously, I could delete the app from my device, reinstall via Xcode and UserDefaults would be blank and fresh. Now when I check that particular journey, UserDefaults are already populated with "didLaunchBefore = 1".

Comment: Sorry. I still cannot replicate it with your example. There must be more to what you are doing than what you have shown.

Comment: @Andrew thanks for looking anyway. I may be getting somewhere..... looks like the init (above) is actually getting called twice, hence the value appears to already be set - proved this with basic print statements. Doing some digging it looks like it could be related to a bug with Xcode 12.5 beta 3.